# NodeJS + Express "Error: -2006,\, Can not bind parameter(s)"

Tags: sql, node.js, express

My company is working on converting from ColdFusion to NodeJS with Express, I'm running into an error trying to update some data in SQLAnywhere.

I have one update function working with 5 pieces of data. I'm working on my second, with 23 data points, but I'm running into an error stating:

> "Error: Code: -2006 Msg: Can not bind parameter(s)."

I can't find any information about this online, not even using the error code. Any help, or pointing me in the right direction, would be appreciated.

Comment: Show your code please. Probably this is based on bad connection info but it's hard to say with what you've provided

Comment: Unfortunately a paranoid boss won't let me. Real helpful, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was trying to save integers into "char" fields on the database. Odd that we never had this issue with ColdFusion, but using "String(…)" around the values seemed to solve the issue.